# ExtJs vtype compare using VTypes with multiple combo boxes

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Have a form where I have two group boxes with two combo boxes each. The first group box is for a deposit payment and the second is for the final payment. The first combo box in each group box is to make the payment a request and the second is to make the payment mandatory. But you cannot make the deposit payment and required payments both set to mandatory.

Therefore, I have been trying to use VTypes to check and compare the two required combo boxes and put out a message if they are both set to YES. I'm unable to get the contents of the other combo box using field,up('form').down('#' + field.pmtField); (where pmtField is defined in the item.)

Here is the code:

(Ext.myapplication extends Ext.grid.Panel)

```
var form=new Ext.myapplication(
{   
    layout : {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch'},
    border : false,
    items: 
    [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Deposit Requirements',
            items:
            [
                {
                    xtype : 'fieldcontainer',
                layout:{type: 'hbox'},
                border: 0,
                items: 
                [
                        {
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'deposit_request_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            inputWidth  : 30,
                            fieldLabel  : 'Requested',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'deposit_request_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            value       : 'f',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        },
                        {              
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            inputWidth  : 30,
                            fieldLabel  : 'Required',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            vtype       : 'depositFlagCheck',
                            pmtField    : 'payment_required_flag',
                            value       : 'f',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Payment Requirements',
            items:
            [
                {
                    xtype : 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout:{type: 'hbox'},
                    border: 0,
                    items: 
                    [
                        {              
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'payment_request_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            fieldLabel  : 'Requested',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'payment_request_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            value       : 'f',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        },
                        {              
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'payment_required_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            fieldLabel  : 'Required',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'payment_required_flag',
                            vtype       : 'paymentFlagCheck',
                            depField    : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            value       : 'f',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is the definition of my VTypes:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();

Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    depositFlagCheck : function(val, field) {
        var paymentFlag = field.up('form').up('form').down('#' + field.pmtField);
        if (val == 'YES') {
            if (paymentFlag.getValue() == 't') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    depositFlagCheckText  : 'You cannot require both dep and full payment amount.',
    paymentFlagCheck : function(val, field) {
        var depositFlag = field.up('form').down('#' + field.depField);
        if (val == 'YES') {
            if (depositFlag.getValue() == 't') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    paymentFlagCheckText  : 'Still cannot do it!'
});
```

Comment: Changed the line var paymentFlag = field.up... to var field = Ext.getCmp('payment_required_flag'); and added the id value to the combobox definition and now it works.

Comment: To use `down` i think you would need to add an itemId to each combobox ie. `'itemId':'payment_required_flag'` and then to get component: `field.up('form').down('#payment_required_flag')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following and let me know the result. Here, I added an `id` both component then try to get component value by `getValue()` method.

```
(Ext.myapplication extends Ext.grid.Panel)

var form=new Ext.myapplication(
{   
    layout : {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch'},
    border : false,
    items: 
    [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Deposit Requirements',
            items:
            [
                {
                    xtype : 'fieldcontainer',
                layout:{type: 'hbox'},
                border: 0,
                items: 
                [
                        {
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'deposit_request_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            inputWidth  : 30,
                            fieldLabel  : 'Requested',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'deposit_request_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            value       : 'f',
                            id          : 'deposit_request_flag', 
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        },
                        {              
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            inputWidth  : 30,
                            fieldLabel  : 'Required',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            vtype       : 'depositFlagCheck',
                            pmtField    : 'payment_required_flag',
                            value       : 'f',
                            id          : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Payment Requirements',
            items:
            [
                {
                    xtype : 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout:{type: 'hbox'},
                    border: 0,
                    items: 
                    [
                        {              
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'payment_request_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            fieldLabel  : 'Requested',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'payment_request_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            value       : 'f',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        },
                        {              
                            xtype       : 'combobox',
                            name        : 'payment_required_flag',
                            labelAlign  : 'top',
                            fieldLabel  : 'Required',
                            labelStyle  : 'font-weight:bold',
                            valueField  : 'payment_required_flag',
                            vtype       : 'paymentFlagCheck',
                            depField    : 'deposit_required_flag',
                            editable    : false,
                            value       : 'f',
                            store       : [['t','YES'],['f','NO']]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();

Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
var depVal = Ext.getCmp('deposit_request_flag').getValue(),
payVal = Ext.getCmp('deposit_required_flag').getValue();
depositFlagCheck : function() {
    if (depVal == 'YES' && payVal == 't') {
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing to make it work. Thanks.